# JavaScript check the element input type onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I want JavaScript to change the design of the text field for the current field clicked.

I want to have only one function which does it and updates the element id for the current field onclick.

So there can be a function which get's the element id for the current clicked field and saves it as an object and another one which changes the design of the field.

I don't want this function to be used only for one field, so getElementsById wouldn't work..

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID? Use the :active pseudo class?

Comment: what is written in your code ?

Comment: JavaScript not CSS bro.. Besides that's very different to onclick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this a a base

```
// set the binding first, on all input elements or target it somehow
document.getElementsByTagName('input').onclick = function(){

    var savedId = this.id;   // save the current id somewhere
    this.id = 'NEW_ID';      // set the new id
    // manipulate the element design as you wish

}
```

You should not change ids of elements though. Try a adding removing a class or something else.

Comment: I'm talking about an element which I don't know its id.. just want JavaScript to check if an element onclick has a text type and if it has, change it's design when onclick.

Comment: You have to bind the onclick though on an element. You will do it either by id, by class, or by tag. Depends on your html layout. I don't know the details, that's why I gave the simplest solution. Just change the getElement part with whatever you want in order to attach the onclick binding on the element you want. Maybe try to select all inputs in the div you have them.

Comment: I could specify a class for each text field, yes. I thought JavaScript wouldn't let you select an element by it's class?

Comment: It does. document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: well safe man.. I'll give it a try!